# How to add something within list in dictionaries? note : list is the value

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to change this:

```
my_dict = { 'inventory' : 300, 'foods' : ['fruit', 'lolipop']}
```

become this:

```
my_dict = { 'inventory' : [300,500,600], 'foods' : ['fruit' , 'lolipop', 'water'] }
```

Comment: try this:
`my_dict['inventory'] = [my_dict['inventory'], 500, 600]
my_dict['foods'].append('water')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert my_dict["inventory"] to a list first and then you can use the append method

```
my_dict = { 'inventory' : 300, 'foods' : ['fruit', 'lolipop']}

my_dict["inventory"] = [my_dict["inventory"]]
my_dict["inventory"].append(500)
print my_dict
```

**Output**

```
{'foods': ['fruit', 'lolipop'], 'inventory': [300, 500]}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this::

```
my_dict['inventory'] = [my_dict['inventory'], 500, 600] 
my_dict['foods'].append('water')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access any element of the dictionary and you can start making changes to it. You can also modify the value of the key altogether.

You have this dictionary:

```
my_dict = { 'inventory' : 300, 'foods' : ['fruit', 'lolipop']}
```

You can modify the inventory part because it is not a list and you can append an element to the foods part.

```
my_dict['inventory']= [300,400,500]
my_dict['foods'].append('lolipop')
```

Answer (score 0):

For you're case, an integer is already assigned to the 'inventory'. So, first make a list containing the integer. Then make the 'inventory' hold the list.

```
x = 'my_dict['inventory'] #x would be 300
list = [x]
my_dict['inventory'] = list
my_dict['inventory'].append(next_item)
```